# How to properly use Variables in Python Functions?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, random, syntax

Building a random generator to determine the quality of gemstones. Running into a syntax error which is crashing the script... here's the code:

```
import random
# Set the basic parameters of the gemstone to determine a description
# and to determine the Gemstones base value.
def gem_size():
    global gemsize
    gemsize random.randint(1,8)
return gemsize
def gem_shape():
    return random.randint(1,4)
def gem_lustre():
    return random.randint(1,4)
If gemsize == "8":
    GemSizeMult = 5 \
    GemDesc = Mammoth
Elif gem_size == 7:
    GemSizeMult, GemDesc = 4, Giant
```

I want the function to simply generate a random number between one and eight and return that as the value for the variable *gem_size*. Where I'm getting the syntax error is when I try to compare the gem_size variable with one of the random numbers in order to set some additional gem description variables a bit later on.

Can someone here provide a working example (that works) of how to set, assign, and compare a python variable using the random function?

Comment: please provide the stacktrace of the error

Comment: i believe your return gemsize should be inside your def function, not outside

Comment: Your syntax is indeed entirely off. There are *several* glaring problems with it, in basic syntax, forgetting to use `=` for an assignment, indentation and using a ``\`` line continuation where you cannot use one.

Comment: `If` and `Elif` really shouldn't be capitalized....

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry for the answer posted

Comment: Your `gem_shape` and `gem_lustre` functions are both fine, but you don't call either to produce a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example of generating and comparing a random value

```
num = random.randint(1,10)
if num > 3:
    print("num is > 3")
elif num == 2:
    print("num is exactly 2")
```

As for your actual program, the below is annotated, there are a lot of issues here

```
import random
# Set the basic parameters of the gemstone to determine a description
# and to determine the Gemstones base value.

def gem_size():
    return random.randint(1,8) # no need to explicitly modify a global
def gem_shape():
    return random.randint(1,4)
def gem_lustre():
    return random.randint(1,4)

gemsize = gem_size() # use '=' when assigning to a variable

if gemsize == 8: # lowercase 'if', 8 shouldn't be a string
    GemSizeMult = 5 # no '\' character here
    GemDesc = "Mammoth" # unless you have a Mammoth variable somewhere
elif gemsize == 7: # lowercase 'elif'
    GemSizeMult, GemDesc = 4, "Giant" # unless you have a Giant variable
```

Comment: ...and fixed this, Thank You! My big syntax problem was the sentence case. I had forgotten that Python was case sensitive as I hadn't used it for several years. Once I sorted that out, most of the rest came together nicely. One thing though, the editor/debugger was showing the error with the _gemsize_ variable instead of pinpointing the _if_ statement instead. Anyone know why?

Comment: @GameDaddy idk if there's a good explanation for not showing the `If` as the first error, but since either is an error I wouldn't think too much of it.  Idk of any programming language that isn't case sensitive though.  are there any?